# Java - Date Pattern matching

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I am new to Java. Please help me. I have a problem with JSON response below:

```
{"GetResult":"{  \"IsDate\": [    {      \"Code\": \"200\"    },    {      \"Message\": \"Fetched successfully\"    },    {      \"ID\": \"722c8190c\",      \"Name\": \"Recruitment\",      \"Path\": \"URL\",      \"Date\": \"14 May, 2013\"    },     ]}"}
```

Its a malformed JSON object. So, i am using Matching pattern to get data of `Name`, `Path` and `Date` and getting `Name` and `Path` successfully as below:

```
 Matcher matcherName = Pattern.compile("\\\\\"Name\\\\\":\\s\\\\\"[^,}\\]]+\\\\\"").matcher(Name);

Matcher matcherPath = Pattern.compile("\\\\\"Path\\\\\":\\s\\\\\"^[^,}\\]]+\\\\\"").matcher(Path);
```

So, from the above lines, i am able to get `Path` and `Name`. So, please help how to get `Date` as well. The format of `Date is 14 May, 2013`. Please help me.

Comment: probably a String.replace is better

Comment: before replace i need to get date content into an array. There will be mutiple date objects in JSON response. So, first i need to store all the date from JSON to string array same as i have done for Name and Path. Please help me through `MAtcher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matcher is almost the same as in your question:

```
Matcher matcherDate = Pattern.compile("\\\\\"Date\\\\\":\\s\\\\\"([^\\\\]*)\\\\\"").matcher(brokenJson);
while (matcherDate.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcherDate.group(1));
}
```

Then you can parse date using `SimpleDateFormat`

**Update**. Full code to read brokenJson from file and parse it:

```
    String brokenJson = Files.toString(new File("1.dat"), Charset.defaultCharset());
    Matcher matcherDate = Pattern.compile("\\\\\"Date\\\\\":\\s\\\\\"([^\\\\]*)\\\\\"").matcher(brokenJson);
    while (matcherDate.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcherDate.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: this doesnt help me. Iam not getting into While condition. Please help me,

Comment: it works for me when I put your broken Json to a file and read it from there (to avoid String escaping in Java). see full code in update

Answer (score 2):

It is the valid json.

Check here [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

parse it like this

```
{
    "GetResult": "{  \"IsDate\": [    {      \"Code\": \"200\"    },    {      \"Message\": \"Fetched successfully\"    },    {      \"ID\": \"722c8190c\",      \"Name\": \"Recruitment\",      \"Path\": \"URL\",      \"Date\": \"14 May, 2013\"    },     ]}"
}

JSONObject parent=new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject obj=parent.getJSONObject("GetResult");
JSONArray array=obj.getJSONArray("IsDate");

String jsondatestring=array.getString(2);
JSONObject datejson=new JSONObject(jsondatestring);
String date=datejson.getString("Date");
```

And if you want to know how to unescape those characters try this

use `Commons lang` libarray and `StringEscapeUtils` class.

Simply use

```
String newString=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(yourString);
```

Comment: I think real JSON is a value of GetResult property

Comment: parsing as JSON is better than to apply regex , pattern matching